# What is the event of selecting an email from the cache?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-events

I have an input that allows the user to enter their email to retrieve the password.
What event in js / jQuery is called when the user selects one of the emails from the email list that was previously entered (cache)?
[image]

I tried many ways but it does not work properly, my code is as follows:

```
$("#input_emailResetpassword").on('blur keyup change click focus', function (e) {
   if ($form_changepassword.valid()) {
       $buttonResetPass.removeAttr('disabled', '');
   }
});
```

What is called when the user uses the **tab** key to select one of the emails in the cached email list?
I want to validate as soon as the cursor is in the input. As soon as the user selects one of the cached emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Input event, it occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user interface. So your code looks like.

```js
$("#input_emailResetpassword").on('input', function (e) {
        if ($form_changepassword.valid()) {
            $buttonResetPass.removeAttr('disabled', '');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user selects one of the emails from the email list that was previously entered (cache) `input` event is called.You can do like below:

```
$("#input_emailResetpassword").on('input', function (e) {
    if ($form_changepassword.valid()) {
        $buttonResetPass.removeAttr('disabled', '');
    }
});
```